# Lenovo touchpad lag/delay on first finger movement

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I’ve got a brand new Lenovo E490 and installed Ubuntu 18.10 besides Win10. While in Windows the touchpad is working precisely, in Ubuntu it does not react at the first several “pixels” when I start moving my finger. Especially this happens when I let my finger lay on the touchpad and try to reach several pixels next to the current position of the cursor to hit a small icon for example. I have installed xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and played a lot with xinput “Synaptics Finger” settings but that did not help. It kind of looks like as if the touchpad needed several milliseconds to wake up.